# Iterate through XML child of a child tags in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Currently, I have an XML file. I want to say, if string is `this` print all the child element associated with `this`. I've documented some of the code that I've tried. I'm using the element tree built in.

## XML

```
<commands>
    <command name="this" type="out" major="0x1" minor="0x0">
        <data bytes="1-0" descrip=" ID"></data>
        <data bytes="3-2" descrip=" ID"></data>
        <data bytes="5-4" descrip=" ID"></data>
        <data bytes="7-6" descrip="  Code"></data>
        <data bytes="12-8" descrip=" Revision"></data>
        <data bytes="13" descrip=" Version"></data>
        <data bytes="14" descrip="   Mask"></data>
        <data bytes="15" descrip="Reserved"></data>
        <data bytes="17-16" descrip="   Windows"></data>
        <data bytes="19-18" descrip=" of Write Flush Addresses"></data>
    </command>
</commands>
```

## Sample Code to Parse Out Names

```
tree = ET.parse('command_details.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:

    if child.attrib['major'] == str(hex(int(major_bits[::-1], 2))) and child.attrib['minor'] == str(hex(int(minor_bits[::-1], 2))):
        command_name = str(child.attrib['name'])
```

I basically want to dive deeper and print the sub tags of the command name.

Comment: Can you give an example of your intended output? Your current code does not attempt to return what I *guess* is your intended output, which is all the `data` nodes.

Comment: ID, ID, ID, Code, Revision... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the children of the child and iterate through all of the grandchildren

```
tree = ET.parse('command_details.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:

    if child.attrib['major'] == str(hex(int(major_bits[::-1], 2))) and child.attrib['minor'] == str(hex(int(minor_bits[::-1], 2))):
        command_name = str(child.attrib['name'])    
        for grandchild in child.getchildren():
            print str(grandchild.attrib['bytes'])
            print str(grandchild.attrib['descrip'])
```

Or if you want to print the full XML line, you can do:

```
print ET.tostring(grandchild).strip()
```

Comment: Hm, it doesn't seem to actually print the values

Comment: Then somethings wrong in your if statement because it worked for me

Comment: hm, weird. I literally copied and pasted your code.

Comment: deprecated function also

Comment: getchildren is deprecated

Comment: I don't know why, but for the life of me, I cannot traverse and get the bytes from this file

Comment: @Ryan are you sure that if statement is functioning properly?

Comment: Well, I can grab the name without any issue.

Comment: All there we go! I have no idea what the issue was before.

Comment: Ah, weird. I enter the if statement fine, but the for loop doesn't work inside of it.

Comment: is it possible to only get the bytes of the data element with the name "this" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83271/discussion-between-ryan-and-heinst).